# Have/Had something/someone + verb meaning

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the construct "*have/had something/someone + adjective*"?
For example, "*He had her tried for treason...*".

Comment: Sorry, but your example does not follow the form of the first part of your question. "Tried for treason" isn't an adjective.

Comment: I so, sorry. I meant more the example I provided. I though "tried" is an adjective.

Comment: Tried is a verb, it's the past tense of 'try'

Comment: Tried is not an adjective. But **tired** is.

Comment: I changed the title of the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it means that the subject has caused something to be done to said someone, but not by themselves.

So if I had you tried for treason, it would mean that I didn't run the trial myself, but I had - for example - ordered someone to try you. If I had you fired, I could have told your boss to fire you, or I could have done something that would cause you to be fired (like planting a photo of you stealing company secrets).

The important part is that I didn't *fire* you myself. I *had* you fired by someone else.

Comment: Yes, but also it is used in less dire circumstances: to have my hair cut, to have my house painted, to have their lawn mowed.